# MySQL table does not update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my code
I have 2 table
booking  // create to keep the booking from member
userinfo //keep username of member

```
<?php

  $ta = $_POST['table'];  
  $day=$_POST['date'];  
  $usern = $_SESSION['username'];  
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password") or die ("can't connect to host");  
  mysql_select_db("register",$con) or die("can't connect to database");  
  $sql = "select * from userinfo where username = '$usern' ";   
  $rs = mysql_query($sql);  
  $row = mysql_num_rows($rs);  
  if($row == 0)  
      {  mysql_query("insert into booking(username) values '".$usern. "' ");  
           mysql_db_query("register");  
      } mysql_close();  
   ?>
```

i don't know why it doesn't update.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you checked if `$row != 0`?

Comment: Your query is not valid.  The `VALUES` list must be `()` enclosed.  `echo mysql_error()` and you'll see a syntax error.

Comment: You should try and use mysqli library. This one is deprecated.

Comment: Ok,i get the answer already. I forget to open $SESSION_START. Thank you :))

Comment: Actually the syntax is `session_start();` <= exactly as shown @user2984946

Comment: I won't be forget this again . Thank you  ( I think it comes from careless )

Answer (score 5):

You're missing your parenthesis in your INSERT statement:

```
"insert into booking(username) values '".$usern. "' "
```

should be

```
"insert into booking(username) values ('".$usern. "') "
```

Answer (score 2):

First things first: mysql is becoming unsupported. Use Mysqli instead. It's not much different...

Then, the issue you have is to leave out the "_db". It's just mysql_query(your request). Plus, the second statement doesn't need to exist.

Need error handling? Include (before ;) "or die (mysql_error())